# Python/Tkinter como retardar un hilo con un sleep de tiempo variable

Tags: python, tkinter, hilos, slider

Cordial saludo amigos programadores.

Me encuentro mirando adentro de bubble sort y cree este script de python funcional:
https://github.com/felipedelosh/tikTokBubbleSortSimulate/blob/main/main.py

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Mi problema en concreto es cambiar el tiempo de sleep con un slider

Pero suavemente... estoy hablando que tenga una velocidad alta en 100% y muy lenta en 10% y en 0% que tarde mucho...

Alguien podría ayudarme? con una formula matemática?

```
def modifyTimeSleep(self, value):
    k = int(value)
    self._sleepTime =  0.02 + 0.2 * (k/100)
```

Como hago para que un slider sirva para acelelar o frenar la animación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tomas el 100% como la velocidad máxima y el 0% como la velocidad mínima, yo definiría un retardo máximo y luego haría una función que aplique el valor inverso, puede ser algo muy simple y lineal, por ejemplo:

```
def calcularTiempoSleep(maximoSleep, porcentajeVelocidad):
    return maximoSleep * (1-porcentajeVelocidad/100)
    
    
print(calcularTiempoSleep(2.0, 100.0))
print(calcularTiempoSleep(2.0, 80.0))
print(calcularTiempoSleep(2.0, 60.0))
print(calcularTiempoSleep(2.0, 40.0))
print(calcularTiempoSleep(2.0, 20.0))
print(calcularTiempoSleep(2.0, 0.0))
```

produce esta salida:

```
0.0
0.3999999999999999
0.8
1.2
1.6
2.0
```

Como ves, teniendo un retardo máximo de 2s, cuando le llamo para el 100% de velocidad, me devuelve un tiempo de sleep de 0s, si le llamo con el 40%, me devuelve un retardo de 1.2s y para el 0% me devuelve un retardo de 2s

Comment: Correcto... esa era la formula que estaba buscando... Aúnque le cambie un poquito cosas: self._sleepTime = 0.01 + (0.15 * (1-(k/100)))  Recuerda: que el sleep nunca puede ser 0.

Comment: @Andres, el tiempo de `sleep` si que puede ser cero, pero para el 100% de eficiencia, yo no llamaría para nada a `sleep`, pues aunque el tiempo sea cero, va a desperdiciar el resto del time-slice que le ha dado el scheduler si hay otros hilos compitiendo por el core, y generalmente los hay, como [dice la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)